# Google Play Market, version number

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play, apk

I have a problem with publishing to play store. I tried to publish new version with Visual Studio(choosed Google play, not Ad-Hoc), publishing took much time. Then in Play Developer Console I noticed that I have two new apk with version number 327681 and 262145:
[image]
 Now I'm trying to revert changes by clicking on "Deactivate" in APK menu but see an error: 
[image]

Can I revert to my first APK? Cause I don't want to increase versions, starting from such a big numbers

Comment: upd: I just have read google documentation, seems like increase of the versionCode is the only one possible solution. Is it right?

Comment: You can't go backwards once you've set the version so high. It is probably recommended to deactivate the two large version numbers and increment your version by only 1 each time.

Comment: @ValeriyPosvistak You are publishing separate a APK per ABI but not following the recommend `versionCode` of using a 8-digit identifier:  https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/build-abi-specific-apks/ Make sure this is really want you want to do.